# Nautilus does not work in auto tiling mode on Pop Shell after opening more than 2 windows

Tags: gnome, nautilus

I am using **Ubuntu 22.04 LTS**. **Nautilus** does not perform auto tiling on **Pop Shell** when opening more than 2 windows. What is this problem ?

[image: Nautilus works so well on 2 windows.]

[image: Nautilus does not work in auto tiling mode on Pop Shell after opening more than 2 windows.]

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS uses the GNOME shell and not Pop Shell.  Please clarify? as you're asking about something that isn't installed on a Ubuntu 20.04 LTS system, thus isn't supposed to work as it's from a non-Ubuntu OS.

Comment: Thank you so much, I got that point. I then asked in Github of Pop Shell and will share the answer for the others.